# Gradle build dependency form external go project

Tags: java, go, gradle, build.gradle

I wanted to give the dependency location from the internal file system instead of the git location.

Bellow is the part of the build.gradle file. I have some internal changes to the **incubator-openwhisk-client-go/whisk** project in the local mechine, so I wanted to add this local depenancy instead of the github original location. How Do I achive this?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.blindpirate.gogradle' version '0.8.1'
}

golang {
    packagePath = 'github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-cli' as String
    buildTags = (rootProject.findProperty('goTags')?:'').split(',')
}

dependencies {

    golang {
        // BEGIN - Imported from Godeps
        build(['name':'golang.org/x/sys/unix', 'version':'7f918dd405547ecb864d14a8ecbbfe205b5f930f', 'transitive':false])
        build(['name':'gopkg.in/yaml.v2', 'version':'cd8b52f8269e0feb286dfeef29f8fe4d5b397e0b', 'transitive':false])
        build(['name':'github.com/ghodss/yaml', 'version':'0ca9ea5df5451ffdf184b4428c902747c2c11cd7', 'transitive':false])
        build(['name':'github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-go/whisk','version':'e452b524cd745f71c913c5acccf72a8daba6dc71','transitive':false])
        // END - Imported from Godeps
        test name:'github.com/stretchr/testify', version:'b91bfb9ebec76498946beb6af7c0230c7cc7ba6c', transitive:false //, tag: 'v1.2.0'
        test name:'github.com/spf13/viper', version:'aafc9e6bc7b7bb53ddaa75a5ef49a17d6e654be5', transitive:false
        test name:'github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/md2man', version:'1d903dcb749992f3741d744c0f8376b4bd7eb3e1', transitive:false //, tag:'v1.0.7'
        test name:'github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew', version:'346938d642f2ec3594ed81d874461961cd0faa76', transitive:false //, tag:'v1.1.0'
        test name:'github.com/pmezard/go-difflib/difflib', version:'792786c7400a136282c1664665ae0a8db921c6c2', transitive:false
    }
}
```

full gradle file is available https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-cli/blob/master/build.gradle